# How to include variables in the React Apollo query and execute it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-apollo

I'm using `compose` to perform multiple queries in a component. I want to be able to use variables for the queries.

1) How do I include the variables in the query?

2) How do I execute the query?

Following is the component:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    View,
} from 'react-native'
import { graphql, withApollo } from 'react-apollo'
import { compose } from "recompose";

import { GET_ITEM, GET_REVIEWS } from '../graphql/query'

const PostingDetail = props => {
    const itemId = props.navigation.getParam('itemId', null)

    console.log("props", props.itemQuery)

    return (
        <View>
        </View>
    )
}


export default compose(
    withApollo,
    graphql(GET_ITEM, { 
        name: 'itemQuery',
        options: ({ itemId }) => ({
            variables: {
                id: itemId
            }
        })
    }), 
    graphql(GET_REVIEWS, { name: 'reviewsQuery'}), 
)(PostingDetail)
```

I want to be able to use `itemId` as the variables for the query, however, the above code displays the following error:

> "message": "Variable \"$id\" of required type \"ID!\" was not
>   provided."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property allows you to configure the name of the prop that gets passed down to your component. By default if the GraphQL document you pass into `graphql()` is a query then your prop will be named `data`. If you pass a mutation then your prop will be named `mutate`. While appropriate these default names collide when you are trying to use multiple queries or mutations with the same component. To avoid collisions you may use `config.name` to provide the prop from each `query` or `mutation` HOC a new name.

**Example**

```js
export default compose(
  graphql(gql`mutation (...) { ... }`, { name: 'createTodo' }),
  graphql(gql`mutation (...) { ... }`, { name: 'updateTodo' }),
  graphql(gql`mutation (...) { ... }`, { name: 'deleteTodo' }),
)(MyComponent);

function MyComponent(props) {
  // Instead of the default prop name, `mutate`,
  // we have three different prop names.
  console.log(props.createTodo);
  console.log(props.updateTodo);
  console.log(props.deleteTodo);

  return null;
}
```

And the key of the variable you want to use is not in the query statement, showing the error message.

**use variables of options**

```js
export default graphql(gql`
  query ($width: Int!, $height: Int!) {
    ...
  }
`, {
  options: (props) => ({
    variables: {
      width: props.size,
      height: props.size,
    },
  }),
})(MyComponent);
```